# Is there anyway to query data from the past on HERE api? (e.g. traffic data from L.A. last week wednesday at 2 p.m.)

Tags: here-api

I've checked the docs, but I found nothing. Is there a way to query data from the past. Is this a feature that is available through premium accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct access to historic traffic data is not available via the developer portal. Please use the contact form to reach out to a HERE representative. (That said, historic traffic data is taken into account for features such as routing, e.g. when asking for a traffic enabled route in the future.)